# Algorithmic problem : Enhanced - Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

The problem is quite tough to explain but I will try my best.

There is total weight W and a bag of fruits.
Then there are n items.
Task is to find the best fit.

The set of items with Max fruits has to be the answer. If the set has same no of fruit then the set with Max weight has to be selected. If that is same then set with max-item-weight has to be the winner.

For W=15, bag of fruits = {A,B,C}, n=5
Items are as below:

1. Which has weight 7 and requires A
2. Which has weight 6 and requires B,C
3. Weight 8 and requires no fruits.
4. Weight 6 and requires no fruits
5. Weight 7 and requires B

Here the follow sets

1. {1, 3} has weight 15, f: 1
2. {1,5} has weight 14, f: 2
3. {2,3} has weight 14, f:2
4. {1,2} has weight 13, f:3

So the answer here would be set with item {1, 2}.

The things that I have already tried

1. Searching all possible combination 2^n (not a good idea)
2. Sort the items by Max fruits and Max weight and then select but does not guarantee best fit.
3. Obviously this can be done with knapsack
   But requires state of fruit bag has to be stored on every cell of dp table. Will take up more space.

Is any further optimization possible?

Another example:
n = 4, W = 1, fruits { A,A,A,A,A}

1. w=0, f = {A,A,A,A}
2. w=0, f = {A,A,A}
3. w=0, f = {A,A}
4. w=1, no fruits

It should select items {2,3}

Comment: just do classic knapsack DP with table `[n][W]`, just make sure fruits are sorted by weight in increasing order. Then just loop over table values from the back - first possible value will show how much items is possible and what maximum weight it will have. Then simply backtracking satisfies the final condition (because fruits were sorted)

Comment: Is there any limit on the number of fruits in the bag?

Comment: Why set {1, 2} with weight 13, f: 3 isn't considered?

Comment: @JuanLopes No there is not limit on the number of fruits in the bag. My bad - Answer should be {1, 2}.

Comment: I tried simple knapsack without sorting. @Photon even when we sort, the second example will not work. Right?